# How to pass a DaysOfTheWeek enum value dynamically through code

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I have the below enum value in task scheduler class, while I am creating a task I need to add days of the week depending on the checkbox selection. If the Monday checkbox is selected, I need to pass only Monday (or sometimes multiple days if other checkboxes are also selected).

In that below code how can I pass the multiple days dynamically?

```
public enum DaysOfTheWeek: short
{
    Sunday = 1,
    Monday = 2,
    Tuesday = 4,
    Wednesday = 8,
    Thursday = 16,
    Friday = 32,
    Saturday = 64,
    AllDays = 127
}

DaysOfWeek = DaysOfTheWeek.Monday | DaysOfTheWeek.Sunday;
```

Comment: What is the type of `DaysOfWeek`? If it's a `short` it should work as you have done it.

Comment: but I don't want to pass in this way. I want to pass through loop depend upon the checkbox selected

Comment: use a ```switch case``` where if a days is selected it picks its value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decorate your enum with the `Flags` attribute:

```
[Flags]
public enum DaysOfTheWeek : short
```

Declare a `DaysOfTheWeek` variable and initialise it to zero:

```
DaysOfTheWeek days = 0;
```

Add flags to the enum value for each day which is ticked. Replace `bool sunday = true, wednesday = true;` here with your code which examines the checkboxes:

```
bool sunday = true, wednesday = true; // this is just proof of concept

if (sunday)
    days |= DaysOfTheWeek.Sunday;
if (wednesday)
    days |= DaysOfTheWeek.Wednesday;
```

`days` output:

> Sunday, Wednesday

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through your select list like this and create your enum value:

```
var days = new[] {1, 4, 32};

var daysOfTheWeek = DaysOfTheWeek.None;
foreach (var day in days)
{
    daysOfTheWeek = daysOfTheWeek | (DaysOfTheWeek) day;
}

[Flags]
public enum DaysOfTheWeek
{
    None = 0,
    Sunday = 1,
    Monday = 2,
    Tuesday = 4,
    Wednesday = 8,
    Thursday = 16,
    Friday = 32,
    Saturday = 64,
    AllDays = 128
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't mention loop, but your reply to my comment does. Do you mean something like:

```
DaysOfWeek = DaysOfTheWeek.Monday | DaysOfTheWeek.Sunday;

foreach (int day in Enum.GetValues(typeof(DaysOfTheWeek)))
{
    if ( day & DaysOfWeek ) {
        /* do something for this day */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As *Shahriar Gholami* suggested, here the complete code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var daysOfWeek = GetDaysOfTheWeek(new List<DaysOfTheWeek> {DaysOfTheWeek.Monday, DaysOfTheWeek.Sunday});
        Console.WriteLine(daysOfWeek); //3
    }

    public static DaysOfTheWeek GetDaysOfTheWeek(List<DaysOfTheWeek> selectedDays)
    {
        var daysOfTheWeek = DaysOfTheWeek.None;
        foreach (var day in selectedDays)
        {
            daysOfTheWeek = daysOfTheWeek | day;
        }
        return daysOfTheWeek;
    }
}

[Flags]
public enum DaysOfTheWeek : short
{
    None = 0,
    Sunday = 1,
    Monday = 2,
    Tuesday = 4,
    Wednesday = 8,
    Thursday = 16,
    Friday = 32,
    Saturday = 64,
    AllDays = 127
}
```